# Print object and get specific contents in Java

Tags: java

I have a project and I am facing a problem I had before again.

We have this Tester file given. Should not edit it.
I want you to focus on this line:

```
System.out.println(bb) ;
```

It prints the object right?

```
import java.util.Arrays ;
/**
   Presents some problems to the BillBoard class.
 */
public class BillboardTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
    int[] profits = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 1, 6, 10} ;
    int k = 2 ;
    System.out.println("Profits: " + 
               Arrays.toString(profits) + "   k = " + k)  ;
    Billboard bb = new Billboard(profits, k) ;
    System.out.println("Maximum Profit = " + bb.maximumProfit()) ;
    System.out.println(bb) ;

    k = 3 ;
    profits = new int[]{7, 4, 5, 6, 1, 7, 8, 9, 2, 5} ;
    System.out.println("Profits: " + 
               Arrays.toString(profits) + "   k = " + k)  ;
    bb = new Billboard(profits, k) ;
    System.out.println("Maximum Profit = " + bb.maximumProfit()) ;
    System.out.println(bb) ;
    }
}
```

Then by printing the object, he expects this result:

```
Billboards removed (profit): 3(1) 0(1) => profit loss of 2
total value of billboards = 23
remaining maximum profit = 21
```

I don't know what method do I have to create in the actual Billboard class, so I can get this printed out. Do you have any suggestions? I want to know the logic behind this, rather than a solution to that particular problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Override `toString` method.

Whenever you print any instance of your class, the `toString` method is called. If you don't override it, `Object's` class `toString` will be used, which returns a representation having `type@someNumber` form.

To print your own representation, just override it, and then your implementation of `toString` will be invoked.

```java
@Override
public String toString() {
    return this.getProfit();
}
```

You can change your returned string accordingly. I don't know what your `k` is, but you can also include that in your `returned string`.

Comment: @MikeSpy.. I just posted one.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rohit Jain! That's exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: `toString` used for different purposes not in this case.

Comment: @RomanC.. And I think downvote on this answer is the moste insensible downvote I've ever seen. And I would love to know `For What purpose you think toString is used for`? Can you tell me, I would love to know.

Comment: @RomanC.. Ah! I just saw that you also answered this question, and commented there. But that was a legitimate comment. And if you think I downvoted there, then I didn't. I downvote on an answer very rarely. So, please don't take it personal. You should never take things personal on SO.

Answer (score 4):

Override the `toString` method. Printing an object relies on that method defined in the `Object` class. By overriding it, your implementation will be used instead of that one.

Consider `println`'s documentation:

> Prints an Object and then terminate the line. This method calls at first 
>   String.valueOf(x) to get the printed object's string value, then
>   behaves as though it invokes print(String) and then println().

`println` relies on `String.valueOf(x)` who invokes `x`'s `toString` method.

An example:

```
public String toString() {
    return "Billboards removed (profit):" + someParam + " => profit loss of " +
           profitLoss + "\ntotal value of billboards = " + totalValue + 
           "\nremaining maximum profit = " + remainingProfit;
}
```

Long story short, you just return a `String` representation of your object where you "describe" its content. If you had a `Person` object, your `toString` would be, maybe, something like:

```
"Name: " + personName + "Email: " + personEmail.
```

Comment: Thanks very much Gamb! It's great you also gave me the return for this example! It's very hard to decide at whom to give the correct answer. You both did a great job explaining me.... But I think I'll give it to  Rohit Jain, cause he was the first to make me understand. But still, thank you! I appreciate it...

Comment: @MikeSpy No sweat! What's important here is that you got to understand it. Keep the good work up.